# Load HashMap values from Xml file

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

How to load a hashmap from your XML and inject it into a real object in JAVA

Comment: it could be done by these steps: parse xml->extract data and save in your hashmap->set object values by hashmap. which step are you on right now?

Answer (score 1):

you can deserialize it from xml directly if you have a proper class representing your map. unfortunately you have to post more informations about your problem so we can help you ...

in any case you should try either [**Simple**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) or **JAXB**. Both can serialize / deserialize a object to XML and back again.

Some documentation:

- **Simple XML Framework**

  - [Website](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Tutorials](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) (see especially [Dealing with map objects](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#map))
  - [Examples](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php)
  - [Serialize HashMap as root element with Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999035/serialize-hashmap-as-root-element-with-simple/12162411)

and ...

- **JAXB**

  - [Reference Implementierung](http://jaxb.java.net/)
  - [Tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)